# How to view commit history between 2 tags in Git after excluding specific folder

Tags: git, github, git-diff, git-log

I am trying to view the commit history between 2 tags in Git after excluding specific folder paths. The below command provides the commit history between 2 tags but not sure how to exclude certain paths

```
git log --oneline  tags/v7.9.1...tags/v7.9.2
```

I tried the below commands but it doesn't seem to work as well

```
 git log --oneline -- . ':(exclude)*path*' tags/v7.9.1...tags/v7.9.2
 git log --oneline  -- . “:!*path*” tags/v7.9.1...tags/v7.9.2
```

Any idea / suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two branches `master` and `test` this seems to work for me:

Here's a standard comparison which shows modifications to a file and a file in a sub folder.

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/logtest (master)
$ git log master...test
commit 7b46c8e215e91d17ef9db33f04f254cccfcd9565 (test)
Author: Martin Kjeldsen
Date:   Thu Sep 24 21:24:02 2020 +0200

    modified test/test on test br

commit e104b257f350724d19f2b5599338b2df81a00b88
Author: Martin Kjeldsen
Date:   Thu Sep 24 21:23:34 2020 +0200

    modified test.txt on test br
```

The following comparison excludes the `test/` folder

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/logtest (master)
$ git log -- . ":(exclude)test/" master...test
commit 1c0b9a4ef128c7fda594b9d2f72b679c714ce55a (HEAD -> master)
Author: Martin Kjeldsen 
Date:   Thu Sep 24 21:23:06 2020 +0200

    test.txt
```